# How to pass dynamic url to infragistics tab

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, infragistics

I am using on demand for webtab how can I pass dynamic values in content URL? I am using the following in code behind and it's not working

```
WebTab.Tabs[0].ContentUrl = string.Format("{0}/AgreementTabContent/Summary.aspx?Id={1}&RegardingId={2}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"], Request.QueryString["Id"], Request.QueryString["RegardingId"]);
```

My aspx page has

```
<ig:WebTab ID="WebTab" runat="server" Width="100%"  StyleSetName="Claymation" >
    <tabs>            
    <ig:ContentTabItem  Key="Summary" runat="server" Text="Summary"
</ig:ContentTabItem>
```

Comment: You can try to store the same URL in the server variable before the page load event and use the same URL defined at server end in the client script using asp.net scriptlet tags you can access the URL. Then find out the client event for on demand webtab and in the same event you can code for assigning URL for the new tab..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked in web config pass nulls

```
      <add key="Path" value="" />
<add key="BetaDirectory" value="" />
```